# Should there be any moisture around a shower valve?

Tags: plumbing, shower, leak, valve, plumbing-fixture

I just had a plumber install a new shower valve in a remodel and when I run my finger around the back of the ring on the front of the valve, I feel a little bit of moisture. It's a large walk in shower and he installed 2 of these valves but I only feel the moisture on one valve.

Is this normal? Is it maybe that the valve is just sweating a bit?

I did this on 2 separate occasions about 6 hours apart so I know it wasn't an isolated incident.

It's a Delta R10000-UNBXHF Multichoice Universal Shower Only Valve Body.

[image]

Comment: Is the valve that is damp on an exterior wall? Sometimes metal parts that are cold will condense moisture, I have seen this happen in the past.

Comment: Nope, interior wall.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be, if you have exactly as depicted in the picture. The Silver Ring just needs to be tightened a little more or it may have a speck of debris disturbing its seal. Don't worry though and leave it alone, if it doesn't tighten easily and not dripping to screw with tile installation. That gray plastic in the center is just the Test Cap that has a gasket behind it and will be permanently removed once he installs the valve's cartridge and shower handle.